# It is possible to use "and" in hibernate "case when...then...else...end"?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following query:

```
select myentity from TEST as test
left join test.org.parent as parentOrg
left join test.clientRequest as clientReq
where test.customId = 1 and (test.dstatus = 1 or test.cm = true)
order by (case when test.request != '' then test.request else clientReq.name end) asc;
```

It works correctly. But I need not only `clientReq.name` but also `clientReq.surname`. Is it possible to combine theese two columns in this `case when...then...else...end`?

Something like:

```
order by (case when test.request != '' then test.request else (clientReq.name and clientReq.surname) end) asc;
```

This one throws exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node
```

Comment: Do you mean string concatenation (ie, surname + name), or a logical AND?

Comment: @PeterBratton, I meant concatenation, but btw is there possibility to use logical AND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're sorting, I presume you mean to concatenate name and surname:

```
order by (case when test.request != '' then test.request else concat(clientReq.name,clientReq.surname) end) asc;
```

See [HQL Query Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) in the docs for more details.

Comment: I meant concatenation, sorry for incorrect explanation and thank you for a help, this solution works greatly.